# MDS with city distances, some values missing

Tags: python, missing-data, multidimensional-scaling

I have a matrix of distances between cities and I want to use [Multidimensional scaling] (MDS) to calculate the locations of the cities. What MDS algorithm is useful for this? Is it available in python?

Comment: Yes it is available in python. See `from sklearn.manifold import MDS`. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461929/4194079) may help you out.

Comment: This is a venerable problem dating back to the 70s. The SAS/STAT literature on MDS discusses this in some detail. Forget that it's from a canned software package, it still has relevance for python solutions.